# Alternative for eTag field in Google Drive V3?

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

I am upgrading my application from using Google DriveV2 to V3.And there was a  field eTag in the Metadata information of the file, which we used to compare so as to know if the file is updated or not as etag changes even if the metadata or content of file changes.

So now upgrading it to V3 , I am not able to find an alternative for eTag value, with the help of which I can compare if the updated version of file available on internet or not.

Comment: there appears to be no alternative to etag it was removed  https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#validatinganidtoken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two choices.

1/ There are currently no plans to deprecate v2, so you could continue to use it alongside v3. For example you could use all v3, but use v2 files.get to fetch the etag. You will probably find that v3 respects the "if-match" header, even if the v3 file resource doesn't include it. NB I haven't tested this! Of course v2 will be deprecated at some point, but then so will v3. That's life.

2/ You could use a combination of `md5Checksum` (for non-Google file types only) or `version` or `modifiedDate` to see if a file has changed.

Comment: Version doesn't change even if we change the content, I tried it,so it cant be used.Regarding md5Checksum it is only for content change, how can I detect metadata change in this case.

Comment: how about modifiedDate ? If it was me, I'd stay with v2 for now. There is no imperitive to migrate from v2 to v3.

Comment: I tried using modifiedDate,it can track some of the metadata changes but not all of them. And regarding migration from v2 to v3, its client requirements.

Comment: I find it odd that modifiedDate tracks only "some" metadata. Be aware that there is sometimes a lag between updates being submitted and modifiedDate being updated.

Comment: Yep it is odd.For an ex. if we rename the file, modifiedDate comes correct, but if we make a document starred or make it shared then modifiedDate remains as is. And I was testing by giving it complete time, not in a hurry that the changes don't sync.

Comment: Odd. My final suggestion would be to use a single v2 to fetch the etag, and v3 elsewhere. Provided it's contained, documented, and an open issue created to review it in 12 months, your client should agree. Point out that Google are saying the two versions will live side by side.

Comment: Settled down with using modifiedTime for now.Thanks for your valuable suggestions.